# iterrows(), itertuples() iterate pandas dataframe with distinct row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using `itertools.islice` with a limit to iterate dataFrame. Here is the condition: I only want `n` number of rows within a column having distinct row values. But what I get is only 10 rows. I want to iterate the dataFrame till I get the 10 distinct values. How can I achieve this?

Secondly, is there any better way to achieve this?

What i have tried so far:

```
def fun(k):
    author = []
    paper = 0

df = query_sqlite_data()

limit = k
for index, row in itertools.islice(dataF.iterrows(), limit):
    entry = (list(row))
    paper = entry[0]
    if author is not entry[1]:
        author.append(entry[1])
    else:
        pass
    
return author

fun(10)
```

Input data format

```
0       1   1
4945    1   1
4946    1   1
4947    1   1
4950    1   1
0       2   1
4950    2   1
5430    2   1
0       3   1
0       4   1
5273    4   1
5277    4   1
5278    4   1
5279    4   1
5430    4   1
0   5   1
5751    5   1
6      6    1
6      7    1
594    8    1
778    9    1
6      10   1
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Desired results:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `print(df["col2"].unique()[:10])` where `col2` is your column name?

Comment: You don't need a loop here at all. If you find yourself looping through a dataframe, there's a better, loopless way 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `if author is not entry[1]:` you want `if entry[1] not in author:`

However I agree with Andrej that .unique() method is much better unless you have to use iterrows() for something else.  Generally you try to stay away from iterating through pandas dataframes unless absolutely necessary.